# how to use XPath/CSS to pick up the value/content of an attribute whose name begins with a colon?

Tags: parsing, xpath

there is an HTML tag =

```
<nav-categories id="MainMenu" :json-data="{some data}">text</nav-categories>
```

I need to pick up the contents ":json-data"
standard methods (`response.css('::attr(":json-data")')` or `response.css('::attr("\:json-data")')`) do not lead to success...
I use Python + Scrapy (response.selector)

Comment: python,  namespace declaration - what is meant?

Comment: When do comes this unusual notation with colon ? Can you edit HTML first to remove colon? What is the context, OS and library you use, tools...? Can you show us your code ?   
Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy [depends on lxml](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#things-that-are-good-to-know) so `lxml` was used in the answer instead of scrapy.
XPath does not allow a colon on an expression but is able to evaluate de element/attribute name.

```
>>> tree.xpath('//nav-categories/@:json-data')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 2314, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.xpath
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 357, in lxml.etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator.__call__
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

Using `name()` XPath function as a workaround:

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> tree = html.parse(r'/home/lmc/tmp/test.html')      
>>> tree.xpath('//nav-categories/@*[name()=":json-data"]')
['{some data}']
```

Answer (score 1):

here is such an option after all turned out:

```
element = response.css('#MainMenu')
json_data = element.attrib.get(':json-data', None)
```

Comment: XML/Xpath it's not involved at this level. `_Element.attrib` attribute it's a [regular dictionary](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#attrib) so `:json-data` it's just another string key.